# how to override button selection without fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue, uistoryboardsegue

So my goal is to be able to go back to a table vc and the topic that was selected remains selected topic with the right questions displayed when the view is loaded again. As you can see below, I have 5 topics...

[image: topics]

This is how the view always loads, I always have the event topic selected with the tableview displaying the event questions and this is the code that handles the button selection:

```
@IBAction func topicPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    eventsTopicButton.isSelected = false
    paymentsTopicButton.isSelected = false
    guestsTopicButton.isSelected = false
    refundsTopicButton.isSelected = false
    profileTopicButton.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true

    switch sender.currentTitle {
    case "Events":
        rowsToDisplay = eventQuestions
        questionTableView.reloadData()
        eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        profileTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        paymentsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        refundsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
    case "Payments":
        rowsToDisplay = paymentQuestions
        questionTableView.reloadData()
        eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        profileTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        paymentsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        refundsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
    case "Guests":
        rowsToDisplay = guestQuestions
        questionTableView.reloadData()
        eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        profileTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        paymentsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        refundsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    case "Refunds":
        rowsToDisplay = refundQuestions
        questionTableView.reloadData()
        eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        profileTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        paymentsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        refundsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
    case "Profile":
        rowsToDisplay = profileQuestions
        questionTableView.reloadData()
        profileTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        paymentsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        refundsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
    
  
    default:
        break
    }
    
}
```

Now the issue i'm having is that when click a cell and segue to a vc from a selected topic different from `Events`, when the vc is exited and segued back to the main FAQ page the events button is selected by default and I want to override that. So I tried to run this block of code in the segued vc when the cell is selected, I get a thread error saying the value is nil.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! FrequentlyAskedQuestionsViewController
    switch segue.identifier {
    case Constants.GuestQuestions.fromGuestQ1AnswerBackToFAQ:
        vc.rowsToDisplay = vc.guestQuestions
        vc.guestsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3084011078, green: 0.5618229508, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        vc.eventsTopicButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
 //        case Constants.GuestQuestions.fromGuestQ2AnswerBackToFAQ:
 //            vc.guestsTopicButton.isSelected = true
//            vc.eventsTopicButton.isSelected = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The `vc.rowsToDisplay..` line works completely fine, but the UI would be misleading if the right  rows were displayed but the button that is supposed to be selected isn't selected at all. I commented out the bottom 2 lines as well after I tried to use those instead but also got thread errors saying the value was nil. I can't understand how the value could be nil, if anyone can help explain this and provide a solution, that would be great. Thanks

[image: gif]

Comment: If I may offer a critical thought politely.... this is a *very* confusing UI. First, why use 5 UIButtons instead of a single UISegmentedControl? Second, what exactly is the need for a UINavigationController? What else besides an FAQ is there? I honestly think you could do something more straightforward - and the resulting code would be *much* less "boilerplate" in nature.

Comment: yeah that was a silly one. UISegmentedControl really is the way, thanks, I needed that. @dfd

Comment: Your problem is that you are segueing *forward* to a new instance of your VC, rather than using an unwind segue to go *back* to the previous VC